# Ajax call not working chrome extension with manifest v2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to play around with a basic chrome extension which goes something like this

```
chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener(function(text, suggest){
       var baseUrl = "http://sample.com";
       var finalResult = [];
              $.ajax({
                     url : baseUrl,
                     dataType : "jsonp",
                     success: function(result) {
                                     for (var i=0; i<result[1].legnth; i++){
                                          finalResult.push(
                                                 {content : result[1][i], description : result[1][i]}
                                          );
                                     }
                                     suggest(finalResult);
                              },
                     async: false
              });           
});
```

This works with manifest version 1, but when I change it to v2, I'm getting the following error. I'd appreciate any help :)

Refused to load the script 'http://sample.com' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should read about [Content Security Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)

complete your manifest file with:

```
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://sample.com; object-src 'self'",
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That doesn't seem to fix it for some reason. So if I have 'http://sample.com/w/api.php?format=json&action=opensearch&search="' and I append a search keyword and call .ajax on that, just mentioning http://sample.com in the manifest file should fix it right?

Comment: oh the link had it though, "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com; object-src 'self'",

Comment: this does not work unless you are providing example.com over HTTPS... if it's a cross domain

Comment: @Richard [content security policy link](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) from google